# Spring Security 4 Authentication Manager Required

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add method security to my Spring MVC application.

I am using 
Spring: 4.2.3
Spring-Security 4.0.3

Problem is, that i get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
```

However when i add

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

to my `SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@43744ca2 to already built object
```

Here my full SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
OntoRAISUserDetailsService userDetailsService;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            formLogin().
            and().
            logout().
            and().
            authorizeRequests().
           // antMatchers("/api/search/users/all").permitAll().
            antMatchers("/login").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().
            and().csrf().disable();

}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


public OntoRAISUserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
}

public void setUserDetailsService(OntoRAISUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}
}
```

Currently my `MethodSecurityConfiguration` is empty.

**UPDATE:**
I had a look further up in the stacktrace, and found that the original exception had some more information, that might be helpfull. So here is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: OntoRais.security.OntoRAISUserDetailsService OntoRais.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ontoRAISUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private OntoRais.datalayer.ontology.service.UserService OntoRais.security.OntoRAISUserDetailsService.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/bwright/Repositories/ontology-toolchain/OntoRais/target/OntoRais/WEB-INF/classes/OntoRais/datalayer/ontology/service/UserService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [OntoRais/config/MethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
```

Comment: I'm not accustomed to @Autowired on the configure(...) method--does that work (i.e., is that method getting activated)?  The [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManager) indicate that the Auth manager will be configured if that configure(...) method is called.

Comment: Ok did a short test about the configure method:
I replaced `@Autowired` with `@Override` and no annotation: all with the same result that i get the above error. However I also noticed, when i added a system.out at the beginning of the method, that the method was not called

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to solve this:

1.) I used a User Service within my CustomUserDetailsService which was secured using spring annotations. I created a separate service for the CustomUserDetailsService only, without security checks (only has the required method loadUserbyUsername)

2.) My new SecurityConfiguration looks as follows:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            formLogin().
            and().
            logout().
            and().
            authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/login").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().
            and().csrf().disable();

}


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(ontoRAISUserDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(ontoRAISUserDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```